# Sonar fails with can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files

Tags: sonarqube, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have just upgraded to SonarQube 6.4 and at the same time moved to mysql.  Whenever I try to parse a particular solution I get the message:

**can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files**

I am running the scanner through VSTS using the new SonarQube tasks.  I have also tried to pass the -X flag to SQ but it is not getting through the VSTS task.  I have also upped the mysql max packet to 512M and restarted both mysql and Sonar servers.  I'm at a loss

Comment: Have you checked the project's inclusion/exclusion patterns?

Comment: What're tasks with settings of the build definition? Can you share the detail log here?

Comment: @ G. Ann I have excluded file types that do not need to be scanned.  What is curious is that when I run the same scan on 6.1 using MSSQL it works.  I

Comment: The settings of the "Prepare the Sonar Qube analysis"  are standard I do have the additional setting of /d:/sonar.verbose=true.The log files are huge 2017-08-14T23:44:57.2369425Z ##[error]00:44:57.205 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
2017-08-14T23:44:57.2369425Z ##[error]00:44:57.205 ERROR: File [moduleKey=DevDeploySIMS8, relative=Packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0/tools/csc.exe, basedir=F:\build\_work\6\s] can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files
2017-08-14T23:44:57.2369425Z ##[error]00:44:57.205

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 17):

Have a look at the post here：
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/958

and follow the advice in the bottom:

> The problem it's caused by /d:sonar.source="Project" or /d:sonar.tests="Project.Tests", just remove and works.

It works for me.

Answer (score 16):

In my case, along with the exclusions, I had written

```
sonar.sources=.
```

Once I removed this, it started working.

Answer (score 8):

"sonar.tests.inclusions=src/**/*.spec.ts" and "sonar.tests=src" are in conflict, take just only one

Comment: `sonar.test.inclusions` is correct, not `tests`

Answer (score 2):

If you have mentioned exclusion property in the test **command** and also in the **sonar-project.properties** file.
Remove it from either of those.

Check all properties, remove any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Access the Sonar, Enter your project screen in the master branch followed:
Click Administration> Analysis Scope> In *Code coverage options *Duplications
*Source File Exclusions
insert the folder that may be being counted twice when reading the code, in my case it was the src folder so I put it in one of the ** /src/ **(no spaces) fields and the problem was solved