# Wondering why pipeline is failing

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.0.2155:sonar (default-cli) on project ps9_omc_itemref_kfkconsumer: File src/test/java/com/michelin/ps9/omc/itemref/kfkconsumer/Ps9OmcItemrefKfkconsumerApplicationTests.java can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00

ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1

Comment: `Ps9OmcItemrefKfkconsumerApplicationTests.java can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files` The error message seems pretty clear. What have you tried so far? I think we'll need more details to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sonar fails with can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638477/sonar-fails-with-cant-be-indexed-twice-please-check-that-inclusion-exclusion-p)

Comment: what is your sonar cmd and what is in your sonar.properties ? update your question with those details and we will be able to help